# Lightbox 2 Implementation

Tags: javascript, html, css, lightbox2

I have tried to implement and use the lightbox jquery function on this [website](http://162.243.219.66/photos.html) however it is not working. I have looked at the documentation and structured the page as the site says yet I do now know why the plug in is not working

Comment: Edit your question to include the relevant code. We need to see what you're currently doing to try and make it work. Looking at your site, it looks like all you did was include lightbox in your site. You aren't using it at all... And your links are broken. Hit F12 to see your console, you'll see 404 errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lightbox resources (the CSS and JS files) aren't being loaded.
Thats why the lightbox isn't working.

Take a look at how did you reference these files, probably you referenced a wrong folder, or something...

Answer (score 0):

You are getting two console errors regarding loading files:

http://162.243.219.66/dist/css/lightbox.min.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

http://162.243.219.66/dist/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Make sure you are pointing to the correct files.